# Look up all posts by status or meta value - performance difference

Tags: post-meta, get-posts

Anyone know if there is likely a big performance difference to these two queries?

1. get all posts by status = TRASH
2. get all posts which have the meta key `_delete_product` and has a value of TRUE

I will be doing a nightly cron purge of all posts which are to be deleted. Best thing is to grab all relevant posts in the most efficient way possible here before looping through them.

Comment: Using `post_status` means you don't need to do a JOIN to postmeta, so it's almost certainly considerably faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `post_status` is stored in the posts table but postmeta values are stores in postmeta table which is usually a much more heavy table than posts. Using a meta in db queries, results in adding a JOIN clause to the query to join this heavy table!

So using `post_status` is definitely a better performance choice.